# Correct way of adding text + php variable in json string?

Tags: php, json

I am struggling a bit to find the correct way of adding a php variable in my json string, with text added just in front of the variable. This is what I have got so far...

```
  $postData = '
  {
    "message": "Web order '.$order_number.'"
  }
  ';
```

When I look at the printout there is a line break just after "Web order", but otherwise nothing seems to go wrong... is this the way to do it?

Comment: Yes, decode the json first using `json_decode` then add whatever you want to add in the object/array(depending if you decoded it as an object or as an array) then re-encode it.

Comment: `json_encode(array('message'=>"Web order ".$order_number))`

Comment: At a glance that looks like it should [work](https://3v4l.org/GVvT6). Are you confident that `$order_number` contains a value that can be cast to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use json string, then make sure you have properly use your values in your array.

**Example:**

```
<?
$order_number = 1;
$yourArray = array('message'=>"Web order ".$order_number);
echo json_encode($yourArray);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
{"message":"Web order 1"}
```

Here, i am using an array for your data `$yourArray` and then use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for json string.

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/180045560f58ada887cf638d1afe68ddd6eaffde)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenate string, use `sprintf()`
Dealing directly with Json can become very harmful quickly. Prefer to use array then `json_encode` instead.

in your case, here is a simple example:

```
$message = sprintf('Web order %s', $order_number)
$postData = [
  'message' => $message
];

$json = json_encode($postData);
```